Coherent effects in inelastic (neutron) scattering
From my understanding, a neutron scattered in an inelastic scattering event, will always be scattered in a random direction. If this is the case, it seems that any form of interference would be impossible. However, I have come across the concepts of both coherent and incoherent inelastic scattering. How is it possible for coherence to exist in inelastic scattering events?

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/297574/difference-between-coherent-scattering-and-elastic-scattering has some info.

Unfortunately, I see the same issue here. While it is confirmed that inelastic coherent scattering does occur, there is no explanation of how an inelastic event can result in any coherence.
